# Robocopy always detects files as "newer" if destination is OneDrive synced

Tags: windows, powershell, sync, onedrive, robocopy

I'm trying to use robocopy to mirror files from a CIFS file share to a SharePoint library via the OneDrive sync client.

Something I've noticed is that all the files get re-copied each time I run robocopy, despite my use of the `/xo` switch. If I run

```
robocopy N:\mysource C:\Users\me\MY SHAREPOINT\testsite - Documents\mydestination /e /xo
```

and then immediately follow it up with

```
robocopy N:\mysource C:\Users\me\MY SHAREPOINT\testsite - Documents\mydestination /e /xo /l /v
```

then the files are detected as "same". But if I wait a few seconds for the OneDrive client to sync the files and then run

```
robocopy N:\mysource C:\Users\me\MY SHAREPOINT\testsite - Documents\mydestination /e /xo /l /v
```

again, now the files report as "Newer".

Using the `Get-ChildItem` command, before OneDrive syncs the files they look like this:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           9/04/2020 12:55 PM          27876 My File.xlsx
```

and after syncing they look like this:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
la---           9/04/2020 12:55 PM          33519 My File.xlsx
```

The `l` attribute appears to indicate an NTFS reparse point, which OneDrive apparently uses for something. I have no idea why the file size increases after it's been synced, I guess OneDrive adds some kind of metadata?

Is it possible to exclude files where the timestamps are the same in robocopy? I can't see a switch for it, but maybe I'm missing something.